# Is it possible to use React/Redux/Saga application without back-end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

Previously I used React/Redux/Saga just as "presentation" layer of an application with Ruby/Rails and Nodejs back-end.
Currently there are couple of back-end services (which I don't control) I should use for authentication and fetching data in my React/Redux/Saga application.
On my local machine I can run my React/Redux app with help of webpack-dev-server, so it could receive requests from browser.

But what about production environment? Is it possible to deploy React/Redux/Saga application without Nginx, Nodejs, Rails?

Comment: yes. all you need is to serve correct js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure. It depends on what are you going to use for deployment. F.e. in our projects, we use `IIS server` for this. It would be published as a simple web app with configurated fallback settings.

Comment: Thank you, Vlad.
What do you mean under 'what are you going to use for deployment' and 'configurated fallback settings'?

Comment: The first was about technology which you prefer for hosting environment, and the second was about settings which helps you to return index page if no html page was found (it would happen cause of your routing in react app, f.e. link `localhost/items` force browser to load `items.html`, but host environment should return index page on this request due to it is just your react app routing)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You can bundle your app to a standalone working "single page" app with webpack. There are multiple good tutorials and examples on the web if you google.

Another simple solution is to use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). With this tool you can [build](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-build) your app with a single command and then [deploy](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment) it to your desired hosting environment.

> ### Create React App
>
> Create React apps with no build configuration.
>
> - [Getting Started](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#getting-started) – How to create a new app.
> - [User Guide](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md) – How to develop apps bootstrapped with Create React App.
>
> Create React App works on macOS, Windows, and Linux.
>
> ### Quick Overview
>
> ```
> npm install -g create-react-app
>
> create-react-app my-app
> cd my-app/
> npm start
> ```